# where can I get realtime ticker data for robots?

Tags: exchanges, api, exchange-rate, pushpool, ticker

I am writing a trading bot and concerned about rate limits.

I need realtime notifications for change in price either like a PUSH api service.

Bitfinex appears to be the only major exchange that offers PUSH notifications, so I am not concerned with Bitfinex. But all other major exchanges such as Kraken are of concern.

How can I get realtime ticker data for the major bitcoin exchanges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Poloniex](https://poloniex.com/) has a PUSH API, check their API FAQ here: https://poloniex.com/support/api/

The other API requests they have said to have **6 request/sec** [rate limitation](https://github.com/BitBotFactory/poloniexlendingbot/issues/167), which in my opinion is still pretty close to real-time if you update the Ticker this way.

[Kraken](https://kraken.com) does not provide PUSH API, from their [FAQ](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#api-call-rate-limit) it looks like a normal user (Tier 2) has a limitation on ticker of 1 request per 3 seconds (**0.33 request/sec**), but will be blocked for 15 minutes when exceeded.

[Coinbase](https://coinbase.com/) has only a PULL API with a 10,000 request per hour (**2.7 request/sec**) based on their [Developer guide](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#rate-limiting), although they operate a separate business called [GDAX](https://gdax.com/) which has a [WebSocket based real-time API](https://docs.gdax.com/#websocket-feed).

Comment: HitBTC also has a Websocket API, see https://api.hitbtc.com/#socket-api-reference

Comment: While it looks like Kraken has a limit of 1 request per 3 seconds, in reality I find that it handles way more without banning. I have a script getting 4 prices from the API every 3 seconds. According to their docs, that should get me banned in about 20 minutes, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Check out 1Forge, they provide a free JSON API for several cryptocurrencies (Bitcoin, Etherium, LiteCoin, Ripple, Dash, and Bitcoin Cash). They also provide data for several standard Forex pairs + gold and silver.

Have a look at their documentation here: https://1forge.com/forex-data-api/api-documentation

If you’re using JavaScript/Node.JS, PHP, Python or Ruby then you can quickly bring in one of their libraries: https://1forge.com/forex-data-api/libraries